# where to add opencv.js into react.js app and how to make available cv instance to the js file?

Tags: reactjs, opencv

I have downloaded opencv.js file from https://docs.opencv.org/master/opencv.js and added this file under the public folder of my react app. Also added script tag to the index.html file. To make available cv instance, I placed '/* global cv */' to the top of my ReadImage.js file. When I go to log cv into the console, then console saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: CV is not defined".

I want to make available cv object to my js file.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Ningxin Hu's (one of the developers - https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/d0a/tutorial_js_intro.html) face detection HTML page source code: https://huningxin.github.io/opencv.js/samples/face-detection/index-wasm.html. The library function calls are in 'index.js'.

Get the OpenCV WebAssembly and the JS library from the git:
https://github.com/huningxin/opencv.js/tree/master/build/wasm